# Problem creating new Profile using ProfMan

Tags: outlook-redemption

I am trying to use ProfMan to setup a MAPI profile, following the example here: (https://www.dimastr.com/redemption/profman_examples.htm#example5)

When i try to set the configuration using:

```
ExchService.Configure 0, , Properties
```

It throws the error: Error in IMsgServiceAdmin.ConfigureMsgService: MAPI_E_INVALID_PARAMETER

I've tried various different values for PR_PROFILE_UNRESOLVED_NAME and PR_PROFILE_UNRESOLVED_SERVER based on the autoconfiguration.xml and just plain server FQDN etc but cant get this to work.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep in minds that example attempts to configure a profile that uses RPC, which is no longer supported. Try to use Outlook 2016 or newer example that creates MAPI-over-HTTP connection.

https://www.dimastr.com/redemption/profman_examples.htm#ROH_Profile_Outlook2016

Comment: That's what I was doing wrong, Thanks :)